# How to get return code from a program in a new terminal? (BASH "Inception")

Tags: bash, terminal, error-code

In terminal I can easily grab the error code of a command

```
> cat thisdoesntexist
cat: thisdoesntexist: No such file or directory
> echo $?
1
```

But doing the same when I run the command in a new terminal

```
> gnome-terminal -e "cat thisdoesntexist"
> echo $?
0
```

How can I grab the error code of the command in the second case (so that it returns 1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to rely on a fifo to communicate between the two shells as `gnome-terminal` does not seem to propagate exit status.

```
sh$ TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
sh$ F=$TMPDIR/fifo
sh$ mkfifo $F
sh$ gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "cat thisdoesntexist; echo $? > '"$F"'"'
sh$ cat $F
1
sh$ rm -rf $TMPDIR
```

**Please notice:** Fifo have the added benefit of being blocking. You might use regular file for simplicity, but beware of possible race conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with a regular file I think for simplicity. I just wonder how come this echoes correctly while `gnome-terminal -x bash -c "cat thisdoesntexist; echo $?"` doesn't..

Comment: Glad to have helped you. Two things: (1) Fifo have the added benefit of being blocking. You might use regular file for simplicity, but beware of possible race conditions. (2) In your command you use _double quotes_ `"`. So `$?` is actually replaced  in the command by its value in the host shell _before_ executing it. That's why I used simple quotes (`'`).